# unable to dequeue a cell with identifier customcellname

Tags: ios, swift

I've seen lots of posts about this error, but none of the provided solutions have worked for me.  I created the table through the storyboard with a custom prototype cell that I have created a class for.  I set the Identifier on the cell.

Cell Identity Inspector: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebkjA.png

Cell Attributes Inspector: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIRxu.png

Storyboard table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAkeS.png

Code to dequeue cell:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FNListViewCell",for: indexPath) as? FNListViewCell

     //filling cell data
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell!
}
```

EDIT: I have tried 2 different things to get it to work, which both are getting rid of the error but are instead resulting in the table appearing empty when the page appears.

1) I tried registering the cell with the table using:

```
self.tableView.register(FNListViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "FNListViewCell")
```

2) I changed the dequeue statement to

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FNListViewCell") as? FNListViewCell
```

Both resulted in the cell object having its UILabel elements as null, but after initializing those and setting values I get a blank table.

Comment: What is error? can you log here?

Comment: Add the code snippet, that you are trying

Comment: @matt , I'm sorry, I'm using the SE application for Android and it looks ok on my phone.

Comment: Put the code in as code and changed the images into the links they were supposed to be in the first place, the big inline images is not how they initially appeared to me when I posted it.

Comment: Please show the code for your FNListViewCell.swift file.  Would like to see how your are configuring the cell before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a separate XIB for table view cell and a custom class for it, then you will have to register it before using it. If you are using table view in a view controller and have an outlet for your table view, then add this line in viewDidLoad().

```
tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "NameOfYourClass", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourIdentifier")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and solution.  I was programmatically modal presenting the table view using

```
let ModalController = FileNoteListTableViewController()
self.present(ModalController,animated: true,completion: nil)
```

I changed it to using a segue defined in the storyboard setup as Present Modally and now the dequeue is working.  I'm guessing it is something to do with the controller not being initialized properly when I was doing it manually.